# Error in Singleton C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to create thread safe singleton class here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<mutex>

using namespace std;
std::mutex mtx;

class MySingleton{
private:
    static MySingleton * singletonInstance;
    MySingleton();
    MySingleton(const MySingleton&);
    const MySingleton& operator=(const MySingleton&);
    ~MySingleton();
public:
    static MySingleton* GetInstance();
    void foo();
};

MySingleton::MySingleton(){
    std::cout << "Ctor\n";
};

MySingleton::~MySingleton(){
    std::cout << "Dtor\n";
};

void MySingleton::foo()
{
    cout << "Inside Foo" << endl;
}

MySingleton* MySingleton::GetInstance(){
    //double check
    if (singletonInstance == NULL){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        if (singletonInstance == NULL)
            singletonInstance = new MySingleton();
    }
    return singletonInstance;
}

int main(void){
    MySingleton::GetInstance()->foo();
}
```

I executed this code in VS2015 and found the **below error**:

```
1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class MySingleton * MySingleton::singletonInstance" (?singletonInstance@MySingleton@@0PAV1@A)
1>E:\CPP\Test\Debug\Singleton.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I am not sure what is missing in my code,just wanted to call the foo() with the singleton instance. Can any one help to figure out the cause of error?

Comment: You never provide a definition for `singletonInstance`.

Comment: I recommend looking at this singleton pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/3807729

Comment: Are you sure that you need lazy initialization?

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you need to initialize `static` members outside of the class, *in a source (.cpp) file*, like this:

```
/** your singleton class definition **/

MySingleton* MySingleton::singletonInstance = nullptr;

/** rest of your code **/
```

Comment: Make sure to do this in the source file, not a header file. Only declarations go in the header.